# Responsive highchart gauge

Tags: angular, highcharts

How to remove extra margin or padding around gauge and make it responsive.( gauage need to take blue area width and height should be auto )

[image: angul]

```
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="published_tuition_fees_1617"
  style="width: 100%; display: block"
></highcharts-chart>
```

**.ts packages**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import HighchartsSolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';
import HighchartsSeriesLabel from 'highcharts/modules/series-label';
import NoDataToDisplay from "highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display";
```

Comment: Could you please share your chart options code

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I Could work on?

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/istibekesi/bm3d1zng/

Highchart sets the height of the chart to 400px by default. So the trick is to set the height of the chart by percentage:

```
#container-speed {
  height: 180%
}
```